# Count number of paths through a matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Please note: **this is not homework**.

This is related to a previous question I have asked, [Calculate number of sequences in frequency matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37655/calculate-number-of-sequences-in-frequency-matrix).

Please refer to this image:

[image: plot of weighted frequency matrix]

(also the image presented on this StackOverflow question: [Plot weighted frequency matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280421/plot-weighted-frequency-matrix))

The plot is from Boring, E. G. (1941). Statistical frequencies as dynamic equilibria. *Psychological Review*, 48(4), 279.

For the full matrix there are $2^{36}$ paths through the full matrix. Boring states:

> Frequency matrix converging upon one-sixth. The diagram is for inter-
>   dependent events with a limiting frequency of one-sixth. There are only 1,947,792 sequences in this matrix

My question: **Since I am reproducing the plot but for 25 trials (instead of 36) how do I calculate the relevant figure for 25 trials rather than for 36 (which is what Boring gives)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take $36$ steps, and $6$ of these are to the left and $30$ are to the right. There are $\binom{36}6=1947792$ ways to choose the $6$ steps to the left. If you do the same thing for $25$ and $6$, there are $\binom{25}6=177100$ ways to choose.

Comment: That appears to be it. As a non-mathematician even the simplest questions can seem daunting. Thanks.